# Support for non-english fonts in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, fonts, fontconfig

I'm having a bit of trouble setting the font for non-english text (arabic to be specific), i tried creating a file named 98-user.conf and copying it in /etc/fonts/conf.d/98-user.conf, the output of : `fc-match :lang=ar` is the  font that i want to be displayed :

```
$ fc-match :lang=ar 
Almarai_Regular.ttf: "Almarai" "Regular"
```

and the output of `loacle -a` :

```
$ locale -a
C
POSIX
ar_DZ.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
```

I want to set a fall back font so when there is a mixed english and arabic text they will be correctly displayed (especially for the arabic text).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed `ttf-droid`

I don't know why exactly but this worked for me.